# OverflowError: timestamp too large to convert to C _PyTime_t

Tags: python, tkinter

This is all of my code:

```
# Import the Modules required to create a window
from tkinter import * # "*" means all# Import the Modules required to create a window
from tkinter import *
# Import other Modules
import sys
import time
# Import the Modules required to create a window
from tkinter import * # "*" means all# Import the Modules required to create a window
from tkinter import *
# Import other Modules
import sys
import time

# Define functions:
def GetTime():
    timeVar = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
    clock.config(text=timeVar)
    clock.after(500,GetTime)
# Function for the 'Alarm'
def callback(): # Function to recieve what has been typed into the input box
    settimer = entry.get()
    minutes=int(settimer*60) # Convert the input to minutes from the entrybox
    time.sleep(settimer) # Sleep until the desired time finshes
    flash = Tk() # The 'Alarm'(flash)
    flash.configure(bg='red')
    flash.overrideredirect(True)
    flash.state('zoomed')
    flash.after(15000, flash.destroy) # set the flash time to 10 seconds
    flash.mainloop()
# Create the clock window
root = Tk()
root.title("Minimal Clock App")
# Main window widgets:
clock = Label(root, font = "UniSans") # The Clock itself
clock.pack()
GetTime()
entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()
OK = Button(root, text = "Set timer", width = 10, command = callback) # Creates a button widget
OK.pack()
# Create the function for the clock
root.mainloop()
# Import other Modules
import sys
import time

# Define functions:
def GetTime():
    timeVar = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
    clock.config(text=timeVar)
    clock.after(500,GetTime)
# Function for the 'Alarm'
def callback(): # Function to recieve what has been typed into the input box
    settimer = entry.get()
    minutes=int(settimer*60) # Convert the input to minutes from the entrybox
    time.sleep(minutes) # Sleep until the desired time finshes (this is where the problem occurs)
    flash = Tk() # The 'Alarm'(flash)
    flash.configure(bg='red')
    flash.overrideredirect(True)
    flash.state('zoomed')
    flash.after(15000, flash.destroy) # set the flash time to 10 seconds
    flash.mainloop()
# Create the clock window
root = Tk()
root.title("Minimal Clock App")
# Main window widgets:
clock = Label(root, font = "UniSans") # The Clock itself
clock.pack()
GetTime()
entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()
OK = Button(root, text = "Set timer", width = 10, command = callback) # Creates a button widget
OK.pack()
# Create the function for the clock
root.mainloop()
```

The problem occurs at the function "callback".

I made this as a small timer application which flashes the screen red for 15 seconds once the timer has finished. whenever i input a number as seconds, it works fine (upto a limit). However once it converts numbers entered to minutes (by multiplying by 60) it doesn't work. Not even 1 minute (1*60). It works if i add the time as seconds (e.g 60 when the minutes variable has been commented).

Also, not sure if there is a way to make the alarm thing happen while the clock is still working?
Sorry, english isn't my first language so I am sorry for any errors in my explanation.

I dont know what to try to fix this. I've searched up but none of the post with the very similar title seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your order of operations in this line of callback:

```
    minutes=int(settimer*60) # Convert the input to minutes from the entrybox
```

This is multiplying the str value from the entry box 60 times, and then converting that value to an int, so an entry of "1", is resulting in a value for minutes of 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111.

The line should instead be:

```
   minutes=int(settimer)*60 # Convert the input to minutes from the entrybox
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just want to point out that while you were right about the concept for the fix, for me the line above didn't work. I had to put *60 in in the time.sleep line after it. Thus making it "time.sleep(int(settimer)*60) # Sleep until the desired time finshes; fix by nigh_anxiety on stackoverflow". Thank you for your help though and i creddited you in my comment (not that my code is going to be published lol).